# Why shutil dont copy django image

Tags: python, django, shutil

I want to copy an image from one Django model instance to another, by copying the actual file with `shutil`. I know that `state.image = self.image` is enough to access the image, but I need a physical copy of the file with a new name.

I have this code:

```
original = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name)

target = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.path.split('.')[1] + '_' + str(state.pk) + '.png')

shutil.copyfile(original, target)

content = urllib.urlretrieve(target)

state.image.save(self.image.path.split('/')[-1], File(open(content[0])), save=True)
state.save()
```

It gives this error:

```
celery_1        | File "/app/state/models/bills/change_coat.py", line 79, in do_bill
celery_1        |     shutil.copyfile(original, target)
celery_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
celery_1        |     with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
celery_1        | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/media/img/state_avatars/file.jpg'
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: It seems that it cannot find your original file. Your output file is `png` your `original` must be the JPG it is complaining about. You need to verify the file in the path it is indicating.

Comment: I'm not clear why you expect `/app/media/img/state_avatars/file.jpg` to be a valid path to a file. Linux installations do not normally have a `/app` folder at the top level, and as far as I can tell, Mac OS would use `/Applications`. Where did `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` come from?

Comment: In your `settings.py`, how `MEDIA_ROOT` is set? Is `/app` is a mount where `Celery` can't access?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel and Corralien, i guess it's a docker image and /app is a project folder

Comment: The path still ought to be verified in some way, though. The error message is quite explicit about what the problem is.

Comment: @sudden-appearance, youre right, its a docker image.
Thats my MEDIA settings:

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' `

Comment: @Corralien, you was right, my Celery image havent access to volumes in docker-compose. I fix it, now all ok :)